# Good Python Module for Saving Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, ide, save

Okay, so I'm new to coding, so don't kill me. I just started about a year ago and I use **repl.it**. I want to learn how to save user data. Also I want to know what python IDE is best suited for this.

Comment: can you elaborate your question clearly?

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632876/storing-user-data-in-a-python-script) has answers regarding saving user data in python. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: An IDE is for writing, running, and debugging your code. It does not really matter which one to use because it should not affect how you store user data. What's *more* important to consider is the structure of the user data, where you want it to be stored (file, database, etc.), how big it will be, how complicated do you want it to be, how often you have to access (read/write) it, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing user data in a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632876/storing-user-data-in-a-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

If you want human-readable cross-programming-language data files, check out the [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

If you want data that is faster, but that only python can read, check out the [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Answer (score 0):

About your IDE Question:
From my point of view, you don`t need an full featured IDE at this point, though PyCharm is quite nice, despite the fact that it's written in java xD... (and it has a ton oof features that will be noise for a beginner (ME 2 ...)) you can make sth. like VS Code quite easy to sth. like a lightweight IDE. If you don't like Microsoft, go for Sublime, or Atom (both also Editors with nice plugins and extensions for Python and other languages...)
If you want to go for scientific python features: check out https://www.spyder-ide.org/
Have fun :-)