# How to locate application preferences folder using OS X APIs?

Tags: c++, macos, osx-mavericks

I have come across an (outdated) code snippet that uses File Manager functions (included in Carbon) to locate the shared application Preferences folder (which in most cases is just "/Library/Preferences"). It is something like:

```
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

...

FSSpec spec = { 0 };   // data type which specifies name and location of a file or folder
FSRef ref;             // data type which references in some sense a file or a folder      
OSErr err = fnfErr;

// find a 'preferences' type folder (specified by kPreferencesFolderType)        
// with the necessary permissions (specified by kUserDomain)
err = FindFolder(kUserDomain, ,
               1, &spec.vRefNum, &spec.parID);

// operate some conversions to put the folder path inside a string where you can 
// then append the app name to it.
FSpMakeFSRef(&spec, &ref);
FSRefMakePath(&ref, (UInt8*)filename, FL_PATH_MAX);
```

(`kUserDomain` and `kPreferencesFolderType` are enum values defined in CarbonCore/Folders.h.)

Unfortunately, many "FS" File Manager functions appear to be deprecated, especially those  using `FSSpec` (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html).

I was therefore wondering: what would it be the current proper way to locate the application preferences folder (without hard wiring "Library/Preferences/AppName" into the code)? Thanks

Comment: There's also `FSFindFolder`, making it easier to avoid `FSSpec`, though it's also deprecated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I store desktop application data in a cross platform way for python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084697/how-do-i-store-desktop-application-data-in-a-cross-platform-way-for-python)

Comment: @thakis Too long since I was versed in this topic... but I guess not because this question was not related to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would dare imagine you want to use something that takes a `NSSearchPathDirectory` — presumable [`NSFileManager -URLsForDirectory:inDomains:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLsForDirectory:inDomains:), probably with `NSLibraryDirectory` and you'll need to add the `Preferences` bit yourself. Based on those options Apple exposes, I really don't think you're intended to read and write from the path yourself — it's just for the user defaults, with the exposed `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` being where you'd just throw other supporting data.

Comment: Originally I wanted to use a pure C++ interface (so no NS-wathever). After some research it seems to me that no such a thing is not provided anymore, so the better way is to write a simple objective-c++ extension to my C++ code. Your answer pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Pedantically, you could technically do it in pure C by interrogating the runtime directly for the `IMP` and then calling that. But it would amount to using the Objective-C method without the Objective-C syntax — it'd be long-winded and ugly.